# Литература для прикладного программирование

Tags: книги

В данной теме прошу подсказать какую литературу следует читать начинающему прикладному программисту не зависимо от языка программирования. С языком программирования определился и выбрал нужную литературу по нему.

Answer (score 4):

1. Алгоритмы
2. Устройство ЭВМ и сети
3. Дискретная математика
4. Операционные системы

Comment: Какую литературу по устройству ЭВМ и сети посоветуете?

Comment: Немного затормозил. Есть на английском роскошная книга Computer Systems: A Programmer’s Perspective. Randal E. Bryant, David R. O’Hallaron, Очень рекомендую. А по русски даже и не знаю книгу такого уровня.

Answer (score 2):

Почитай книги Эндрю Таненбаума. Он хорошо пишет. 
Когда прочтешь его книги, читай книжки по языку, а затем советую порешать различные задачки. Это поможет научится тебе мыслить алгоритмически и заодно запомнишь синтаксис языка и некоторые функции.

Comment: Таненбаум рулит! +1

Answer (score 1):

Ко всем вышеперечисленным ответам, добавлю лишь, что хорошему программисту необходимо (хотя бы выборочно) прочитать книгу "Искусство программирования" Кнута. Она даёт базовые и глубокие понятия о программировании, не затрагивая конкретных языков. Однако, книга не из простых в освоении.
Также могу поделиться ссылкой с хабра - 5 книг, которые должен прочитать каждый программист. Все книжки хороши, но не обязательно всё читать. Может что-то понравится и вам.
[Ссылка на Хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/development/135897/)